# Python subprocess, communicate, and multiprocessing/multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I have a script that executes a compiled fortran module. Input then has to be passed to this process in the form of a filename and enter must be pressed to initiate processing. I have no real control over the nature of the fortran executable it is what it is.

I am using subprocess and communicate to handle this from python and it works well. Problem is I need to process 100's to 1000's of files and doing them sequentially is slow. While I expect I will eventually run into an I/O bottleneck at the HDD current, execution times are nowhere near this limit.

I attempted to simply wrap the method spawning the subproccess in a multithreading ThreadPoolExecutor but found that only a small subset of the files actually get processed (roughly every 20, but it varies) and the rest of the files are created but are empty (each is 0 kb and has no contents - as though the subprocess that spawned them was killed prematurely just after creating the handle)

I have tried using instead subprocess.run with an input argument, custom os.pipes, TemporaryFile as a pipe, spawning all the subprocesses first then multithreading calls to communicate, and manual delays after spawning the process before communicating, all to no avail.

If I spawn the subprocesses first I can confirm by inspection that the stdout, stdin, and stderr pipe for each has a unique identifier.

This is the code that calls the fortran module

```
def run_CEA2(fName_prefix):
    print(fName_prefix)
    CEA_call = subprocess.run('FCEA2.exe', input='{}\n'.format(fName_prefix), encoding='ascii', 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            shell=True, cwd=None, check=False)
    if 'DOES NOT EXIST' in CEA_call.stdout:
        raise RuntimeError('\nERROR: Stdout returned by run_CEA()\n'+'\t'.join([line+'\n' for line in CEA_call.stdout.split('\n')]))
    else:
        return True
```

This is the code that calls the above method asynchronously

```
import concurrent.futures
def threadedRun(fName):
    print('\tExecuting file {}'.format(fName))
    run_CEA(fName)      
    
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    executor.map(threadedRun, fNames)            
print('\tDone.')
```

Here is a version of run_CEA using Popen and communicate

```
def run_CEA(fName_prefix):
    print(fName_prefix)
    p = subprocess.Popen(['FCEA2.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    return_str =  p.communicate(input=('{}\n'.format(fName_prefix)).encode())[0].decode()
    if 'DOES NOT EXIST' in return_str:
        raise RuntimeError('\nERROR: Stdout returned by run_CEA()\n'+'\t'.join([line+'\n' for line in return_str.split('\n')]))
    else:
        return True
```

I do not understand what it causing the premature closure of spawned processes. As stated above I can pre-spawn all the sub processes and then iterate through a list and of these and process each in turn.

When adding concurrent futures to the mix it seems signals get crossed and multiple spawned processes are killed at a time.

Interestingly when I used concurrent futures only to process the pre-populated list of subprocesses behaviour was the same. Regardless of all processes already being present (not being spawned on the fly as the communicate and close process was occuring) output was produced for roughly every 20th process in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly the issue was a Fortran issue and became obvious when I stopped piping stderr and allowed it to pass to the console where I was greeted by:

> forrtl: severe (30): / process cannot access file because it is being
> used by another process.

The Fortran executable being used was not just reading from a binary but also locking it with write permissions meaning that it could not be called concurrently by more than one instance of the executable.

To get around this at runtime I spawn n temporary folders each with a complete copy of the Fortran executable and its dependencies. Then use the 'cwd' argument in the call to subprocess run to have a bunch of threads and crunch through the files.

If you are familiar with the NASA CEA code that is what is being called. For completeness below is code for anyone that might benefit.

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
from threading import Thread, Lock, current_thread
import queue 
import functools
import threading

def run_CEA(fName_prefix,working_folder=None):
    CEA_str = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(working_folder,'FCEA2.exe'))
    CEA_call = subprocess.run(CEA_str, input='{}\n'.format(fName_prefix),
                              encoding='ascii', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                              shell=False, cwd=working_folder, check=False)        
    if 'DOES NOT EXIST' in CEA_call.stdout:
        raise RuntimeError('FCEA2.exe could not find specified input file\n'
            +'\t'.join([line+'\n' for line in CEA_call.stdout.split('\n')]))
    elif CEA_call.stderr:
        raise RuntimeError('Error occured in call to FCEA2.exe\n'
            +'\t'.join([line+'\n' for line in CEA_call.stderr.split('\n')]))    
    else:
        return 1

def synchronized(lock):
    """ Synchronization decorator """
    def wrap(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def newFunction(*args, **kw):
            with lock:
                return f(*args, **kw)
        return newFunction
    return wrap
        
class CEA_Queue(queue.Queue):
    """ Based on template at provided by Shashwat Kumar found @
    https://medium.com/@shashwat_ds/a-tiny-multi-threaded-job-queue-in-30-lines-of-python-a344c3f3f7f0"""

    inp_folder = os.path.abspath('.//inp_files')
    out_folder = os.path.abspath('.//out_files')    
    run_folder = os.path.abspath('.//workers')
    exe_folder = os.path.abspath('.//cea_files')
    
    req_cea_files = ["FCEA2.exe",
                     "b1b2b3.exe",
                     "syntax.exe",
                     "thermo.lib",
                     "trans.lib"]
    lock = Lock()

    @classmethod
    def test_dirs_cls(cls):
        print('test_dirs_cls:')
        for dirname in ('inp_folder','out_folder','run_folder','exe_folder'):
            print(dirname,':',getattr(cls,dirname))

    def test_dirs_self(self):
        print('test_dirs_self:')
        for dirname in ('inp_folder','out_folder','run_folder','exe_folder'):
            print(dirname,':',getattr(self,dirname))


    @staticmethod
    def clean_folder(target,ignore_list=[]):
        if os.path.isdir(target):                
            for fName in os.listdir(target):
                fPath = os.path.join(target,fName)        
                if os.path.isfile(fPath) and not fName in ignore_list:
                    os.remove(fPath)
                elif os.path.isdir(fPath) and not fName in ignore_list:
                    shutil.rmtree(fPath)    
    
    @classmethod
    def setup_folders(cls):
        for folder in (cls.out_folder,cls.inp_folder,cls.run_folder):
            if not os.path.isdir(folder):
                os.mkdir(folder)
            else:
                cls.clean_folder(folder)
                
        if not os.path.isdir(cls.exe_folder):                                    
            raise ValueError("Cannot find exe folder at:\n\t{}".format(cls.exe_folder))    
        else:
            cls.clean_folder(cls.exe_folder,ignore_list=cls.req_cea_files)

    @classmethod
    def cleanup(cls):                 
        cls.clean_folder(cls.run_folder)  
        out_files = []
        for fName in os.listdir(cls.inp_folder):
            if '.out' == fName[-4:]:
                try:
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(cls.inp_folder,fName),
                                os.path.join(cls.out_folder,fName)) 
                    out_files.append(os.path.join(cls.out_folder,fName))
                except Exception as exc:
                    print('WARNING: Could not move *.out file\n{}\n{}'.format(fName,exc))
        return out_files
    
    @classmethod
    def gather_inputs(cls):
        inp_files = []
        for fName in os.listdir(cls.inp_folder):
            if '.inp' in fName[-4:]:                
                inp_files.append(os.path.join(cls.inp_folder,fName))
        return inp_files
    
    @classmethod
    def set_dirs(cls,inp_folder=None,out_folder=None,
                 run_folder=None,exe_folder=None):
        if not inp_folder is None:
            cls.inp_folder = os.path.abspath(inp_folder)
        if not out_folder is None:
            cls.out_folder = os.path.abspath(out_folder)
        if not run_folder is None:
            cls.run_folder = os.path.abspath(run_folder)
        if not exe_folder is None:
            cls.exe_folder = os.path.abspath(exe_folder)            
        
    def __init__(self, num_workers=1,inp_folder=None,out_folder=None,
                 run_folder=None,exe_folder=None):                        
        queue.Queue.__init__(self) 
        self.set_dirs(inp_folder,out_folder,run_folder,exe_folder)
        self.setup_folders()                        
        self.num_workers = num_workers       
        self.n_task = 0
        self.n_complete = 0
        self.update_every = 10.
        self.last_update = 0
                   
    def add_task(self, fName):
        self.put(fName)
            
    def schedule_tasks(self):
        inp_files = self.gather_inputs()
        for fName in inp_files:
            self.add_task(fName.split('.inp')[0])
        self.n_task = len(inp_files)
        self.n_complete = 0
        self.last_update = 0
        return inp_files
    
    def progress(self):
        return (self.n_complete/self.n_task)*100
        
    
    def start_workers(self):
        self.worker_threads = []
        for i in range(self.num_workers):            
            k = str(i)
            worker_folder =  os.path.join(self.run_folder,k)            
            try:
                os.mkdir(worker_folder)
                for fNameExe in os.listdir(self.exe_folder):
                    shutil.copy(os.path.join(self.exe_folder,fNameExe),os.path.join(worker_folder,fNameExe))                   
            except Exception as exc:
                raise exc                                                                      
            t = Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.worker_folder = worker_folder
            t.start()
            self.worker_threads.append(t)
        
    def worker(self):
        while True:
            try:
                worker_folder = current_thread().worker_folder             
                fName = self.get()        
                rel_path = os.path.relpath(fName,worker_folder)
                run_CEA(rel_path,worker_folder)                                     
            except Exception as exc:
                print('ERROR: Worker failed on task\n\tFolder:{}\n\tFile:{}\n\t{}'.format(worker_folder,fName,exc))
            finally:
                self.task_done()
                with self.lock:
                    self.n_complete+=1
                    current_progress = self.progress()
                    if (self.last_update==0 or current_progress==100. or
                        current_progress-self.last_update>=self.update_every):                        
                        print('\tCurrent progress: {:>6.2f}%'.format(current_progress))
                        self.last_update = current_progress
    
    def run(self):        
        inp_files = self.schedule_tasks()
        self.start_workers() 
        self.join()
        out_files = self.cleanup()
        return out_files
    
    def tests(self,n):
        inp_str = """! EXAMPLE 1
        ! (a) Assigned-temperature-and-pressure problem (tp).
        ! (b) Reactants are H2 and Air. Since "exploded ll formulas are not given,
        !     these formulas will be taken from the thermodynamic data library,
        !     thermo. lib.
        ! (c) Calculations are for two equivalence ratios (r,eq.ratio =1,1.5) .
        ! (d) Assigned pressures are I, 0.1, and 0.01 atm (p(atm)=l, .1, .01).
        ! (d) Assigned temperatures are 3000 and 2000 K (t(k)=3000,2000).
        ! (f) 'only' dataset is used to restrict possible products.
        ! (g) Energy units in the final tables are in calories (calories).

        problem case=Example-1 tp p(atm)=1,.1,.01, t(k)=3000,2000,
                r,eq.ratio=1,1.5
        reac
        fuel= H2  moles = 1.
        oxid= Air moles = 1.
        only Ar C CO CO2 H H2 H2O HNO HO2 HNO2 HNO3 N NH
        NO N2 N2O3 O O2 OH O3
        output calories
        end
        """        
        self.setup_folders()     
        for i in range(n):
            fName = 'test{:0>4}'.format(i)
            fName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.inp_folder,fName+'.inp'))    
            f = open(fName,'w')
            f.write(inp_str)
            f.close()            
        return self.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if True:
        import time
        start_time = time.time()
        Q = CEA_Queue(12)
        out_files = Q.tests(10_000)
        end_time = time.time()
        print('Processing took {:5.2f}'.format(end_time-start_time))
```

On my 8 core machine the sweet spot is at about 12 threads. Below is an example curve comparing runtime to number of threads handling the workload for a problem.

[image: Processing Time vs. Number of Threads]